# How to get std::string from command line arguments in win32 application?

Tags: c++, string, command-line, arguments, std

So now I have a

`int main (int argc, char *argv[]){}`

how to make it string based? will `int main (int argc, std::string *argv[])` be enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a string out of the input parameters passed, you can also 
add character pointers to create a string yourself

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

string passedValue;
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
 passedValue += argv[i];
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "`+=`" would mash them all together. `passedValue.append(argv[i]).append(" ")` would look nicer.

Answer (score 27):

You can't change main's signature, so this is your best bet:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> params(argv, argv+argc);
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yep, `+1` from me, although usually you want `argv+1, argv+argc` (because `argv+0` is the application name).

Comment: @sbi, yeah- that's important to keep in mind, but I was trying to keep it simple :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it that way, as the main function is declared explicitly as it is as an entry point.  Note that the CRT knows nothing about STL so would barf anyway.  Try:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> args;
    for(int i(0); i < argc; ++i)
        args.push_back(argv[i]);

    // ...

    return(0);
}; // eo main
```

Comment: vow. like that i(0) syntax +1

Comment: Since you know the size of the resulting vector, you could use vector's size constructor to preallocate, avoiding possible multiple reallocations with .push_back().  You could also use vector's iterator constructor to avoid having to write the loop yourself.

Comment: @luke, yup I saw your response and +1'd it as it is far cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 3):

That would be non-standard because the Standard in `3.6.1` says

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function.  This function **shall not be overloaded.  It shall have  a  return  type  of  type int**,  but  otherwise  its  type  is  implementation-defined.  All  implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of main:
>
> `int main() { /* ... */ }`
>
> and
>
> `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @Chubsdad : I use Foxit `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

No. That is not allowed. If present, it is mandated to be char *argv[].

BTW, in C++ main should always be declared to return 'int'

Answer (score 2):

main receives char*.  you will have to put the argv array into std::strings yourself.

Comment: main does not pass anything. instead, main is passed char* by the CRT